# Mean value independent from cos

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Why is the mean value E[X(t) cos(2πft)]=cos(2πft) E[X(t)] ? X(t) We can take f as a constant , but can  this equality be applied every time we have a cos in the mean value?

This a part of an exercise where in the given solution this is applied

[image]

Where the probability of f=fc is 9/10 and f=fc+ε is 1/10

Comment: What are you averaging over? Apparently not over $t$, otherwise $t$ couldn't appear as a free variable outside the expectation?

Comment: @joriki yes I saw this equality exactly like that , averaging over t

Comment: Where did you get this from. Can you provide some context? It may **not** necessarily mean $E[X(t)]=\int xf_{X(t)}(x)dx$.

Comment: @TonyHellmuth Yes of course let me edit the question , give me a few minutes

Comment: @TonyHellmuth I edited the post

Comment: $A$ is a constant so $\frac{A^2}{2}$ can be taken outside the expectation.  Then you deal with the two possible values of $f$ and their probabilities.  It does not say $E[X(t) \cos(2πft)]=\cos(2πft) E[X(t)]$

Comment: @Henry it actually implies that because in the image above , the A squared/ 2 cos(2πfct) is supposed to be like this 9/10 E[ A squared/ 2 cos(2πfct) ] , but he has taken completely off the E[ ] and left only the inside. Same for 1/10... .

Comment: The image doesn't correspond at all to what you typed. a) In the image, there's a mix of $\tau$ and $t$ that doesn't seem to make much sense. Perhaps these are just typos in the image, though. b) The right-hand side is not at all the right-hand side that you typed. It actually has two different cosine terms for two different cases, as one might expect. Also, in a comment above you wrote that you're averaging over $t$, but that's not what the expectation operator is doing in the image. There's a lot that you need to get straightened out here.

Comment: @joriki the τ is actually a typo of the person who wrote this (Sorry I forgot to mention). Other than that in a discussion related to this image , someone suggested that the equality in my question is the reason it is done like that, because if you say that the cos(...) in the image is like the cos in the equality and there is no X(t) or X(t)=A^2/2 so it is constant , then you could get the right hand side of the image equation. If you understand what is going on please explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your image, the expectation is being taken not with respect to $t$ (or $\tau$), but with respect to a random event on which the value of $f$ depends. With probability $\frac9{10}$, $f$ takes the value $f_c$, and with probability $\frac1{10}$ it takes the value $f_c+\epsilon$. Then by the definition of the expectation, we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb E\left[\frac{A^2}2\cos(2\pi ft)\right]
&=&
\mathbb P(f=f_c)\frac{A^2}2\cos(2\pi f_ct)+\mathbb P(f=f_c+\epsilon)\frac{A^2}2\cos(2\pi (f_c+\epsilon)t)
\\
&=&
\frac9{10}\cdot\frac{A^2}2\cos(2\pi f_ct)+\frac1{10}\cdot\frac{A^2}2\cos(2\pi (f_c+\epsilon)t)\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

This is a thoroughly unmysterious application of the expectation operator and has nothing to do with the equation that you surmised from it. The only thing that we can take outside the expectation operator here is $\frac{A^2}2$, which doesn't depend on $f$.